# Package.json and node_modules folder does not appear

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg, hardhat, solc

I am using yarn, and when running `yarn add solc` in the terminal it installs everything but the *node_modules* folder and *package.json* do not appear.

What am I doing wrong?

I have tried to find out what could be the problem, and everyone says something about "dependencies" but I don't understand.

Comment: Does it show anything when you write `ls .` or `dir`? assuming you're using vscode, sometimes it doesn't update instantly

Comment: Try using `yarn init`